# Rahul Can't be Found

Tags: support, spam, users

Rahul submitted this [answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/39943/29140) to this [question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/34071/29140). Here's a screenshot: [image]

I can't see his/her profile. Did he/she submitted the answer and deleted immediately the profile?

Comment: FMS, post got deleted !!

Answer (score 4):

No, Rahul's account was destroyed because Rahul is a spammer. This deletes all their "content".

It was a spam answer from an unregistered account so neither we nor they have lost anything of value.

If they want to contribute useful answers then they can create a new account and try again.

It's worth noting that in all the months I've been destroying spammers on sight not one has come back to complain that their account got deleted.

Comment: The answer was a valid one !!

Comment: @JacobJanTuinstra - it doesn't stop it being a spam answer. There was no acknowledgement that the application was their application. It only existed to promote the posters application. It reads the same as the tens of spammy answers I see every week.

Comment: I've seen worse (even with my little time here on [main]). If the `URL` was styled I wouldn't have noticed.

Comment: @JacobJanTuinstra - if you've seen worse please flag it so it can be dealt with.

Comment: Of course, I flagged those myself (for your attention..haha). Somehow the answer of Rahul was acceptable to my. PS: is FMS allowed on [meta]?

Comment: @JacobJanTuinstra - It depends on what FMS means :) Well if he'd declared his affiliation I would have let it stand. They're the rules.

Comment: On a Saturday evening, discussing with ChrisF. If my profile was empty, I could suggest glogingapp as well, couldn't I? .... me sideways

Comment: @JacobJanTuinstra - yes you could suggest the application - but I'm sure you've seen the "I'm not affiliated with this" comments that often go along with such suggestions.